# share data between two user control in c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, user-controls

I everybody,

I have a program which contain 2 usercontrols, in the usercontrol1 there is a `list<object> ListObject`, I would like to get this list in the code behind of the usercontrol2. I heard about MVVM or binding but if someone would like to help me with that and explain me the cleanest way to do that, it would be really nice. thank you very much :) 
I tried Binding but i'm not sure to understand how to use it :

code behind :

```
public List<Conf> listConf;
```

WPF :

```
DataContext="{Binding Listconf}"
```

?

Comment: "get this list in the code behind of the usercontrol2" - how are you going to use this list inside usercontrol2, are you going to output its content on UI? Do you need to update this list in usercontrol1 and get changing notifications in usercontrol2?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a common ViewModel class for those two controls, then put all shared data in it and bind the `DataContext` of both controls to that class.

Also, don't bind `DataContext` to your list. Instead you should do that with `ItemsSource` of your `ListBox` or `ListView`, whichever you use.

That is what you should do if you are using `MVVM`.

Comment: Alright, i'm not so familiar with MVVM so i will try what you say by checking some example on the internet but thx you very much for this hint :)

Comment: @Armatita is there another way to do that or MVVM is the best way to  do it ?

Comment: "then put all shared data in it and bind the DataContext of both controls to that class. " how to put all shared data in the viewmodel ?

Comment: Yes, MVVM is probably the best way.

Comment: In your case, putting all shared data in viewmodel means moving your list there.

Comment: ok thx :) @JohnMellor, but  how to move the list in the commonViewModel Class ? and then how to access this list from the other UC ?

Comment: i could declare the list in the commonViewModel class and set its value from one class and get the value from the other ?

Comment: If you use MVVM, you shouldn't have any code behind in your controls, so all methods which manipulate that list should also be in viewmodel. You call those methods using commands. Check out some tutorials on MVVM bindings and commands. You can start here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial